# Database MASTER does not start after restoring to another instance

Tags: sql-server

I lost my SQL Server 2014 instance and restored the MASTER database on another instance to retrieve the Logins, but when I tried to start the instance the following error message is displayed:

```
FCB::Open failed: Could not open file G:\DATA\DATABASES.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)

FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'G:\DATA\DATABASES.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
```

This error occurs for the 32 databases I had in the instance I lost, in this new instance I don't have any of these 32 databases and i don't have the same letters on the disk drives.

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to restore the databases: attaching the files or restoring backups?

Comment: I would expect the instance to start as long as the system database file locations are the same as the original server. The user databases will be marked as suspect. Do you have errors for system db files?

Comment: The message is quite clear the mdf files of master database is NOT located at `G:\DATA\DATABASES.mdf` plus the name should be master.mdf so it seems its location issue

Comment: The question is whether Fernendo modified the actual error message, and if so, what the original error message referred to. Short story is that the boot sequence is to find files for master through the registry, create tempdb based on info in master and find model based on info in master. If any of those fails, then SQL Server doesn't start. Failure to recover other databases doesn't prohibit SQL Server to start. (I know the responders here knows this already :-) ).

Comment: Sounds like the restore for `master` should have had a `MOVE` parameter. Now you're a bit stuck, you probably need to change the service startup parameters. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#master also https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6883/sql-server-move-database-files-for-master/